# 'angular-fusioncharts' is not in the npm registry

Tags: angularjs, fusioncharts

I am getting following error when I try to include `angular-fusioncharts` in my package.json:

> 'angular-fusioncharts' is not in the npm registry.

Answer (score 0):

Try including `ng-fusioncharts` as decency like

```
angular.module("myApp", ["ng-fusioncharts"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the Angular-FusionCharts
In the terminal run the following command:

```
$ npm install angular-fusioncharts --save
```

Also install FusionCharts, if it is not already installed:

```
$ npm install fusioncharts --save
```

Import the Angular FusionCharts module

In the root Angular @NgModule import FusionChartsModule from angular-fusioncharts and add the FusionChartsModule as a dependency.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// Import angular-fusioncharts
import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular-fusioncharts';

// Import FusionCharts library
import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';

// Load FusionCharts Individual Charts
import * as Charts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
// Add other dependecies like Charts, PowerCharts, Widgets, Maps
// import FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion';
// import Maps from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.maps';
// import World from 'fusioncharts/maps/fusioncharts.world';



// Use fcRoot function to inject FusionCharts library, and the modules 
// you want to use
//FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, [Comma separated charts and features]) 
FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts)

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FusionChartsModule // Include in imports
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Document reference - https://fusioncharts.github.io/angular-fusioncharts/#/ex1